# Docker, not able to create hello-world container

Tags: docker, debian

I am new to the docker world. Tried a bit on Windows with some docker containers. Now i installed a Debian 11 system (fresh installation with a provide image by my hoster) I followed [the introductions here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) and used the repository to install docker.

When trying to run the hello-world container, i get the following output.

```
root@Debian-bullseye-latest-amd64-base ~ # sudo docker run hello-world 
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally latest: 
Pulling from library/hello-world 2db29710123e: 
Pull complete Digest: sha256:ffb13da98453e0f04d33a6eee5bb8e46ee50d08ebe17735fc0779d0349e889e9 
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest 
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: 
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: 
error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: 
apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory: unknown. 
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container:
```

I as well followed the post installation instrductions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

docker info:

```
root@Debian-bullseye-latest-amd64-base \~ # docker info
Client:
Context:    default
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
Version:  v0.10.2
Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
Version:  v2.16.0
Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
Containers: 3
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 3
Images: 1
Server Version: 23.0.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Using metacopy: false
Native Overlay Diff: true
userxattr: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Cgroup Version: 2
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
init version: de40ad0
Security Options:
apparmor
seccomp
Profile: builtin
cgroupns
Kernel Version: 5.10.0-21-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 62.8GiB
Name: Debian-bullseye-latest-amd64-base
ID: 4c1574ea-2b4a-4534-9849-e023bbd2a69b
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode: false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127\.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker version:

```
root@Debian-bullseye-latest-amd64-base \~ # docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           23.0.1
API version:       1.42
Go version:        go1.19.5
Git commit:        a5ee5b1
Built:             Thu Feb  9 19:46:54 2023
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          23.0.1
API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.19.5
Git commit:       bc3805a
Built:            Thu Feb  9 19:46:54 2023
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          1.6.18
GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
runc:
Version:          1.1.4
GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
docker-init:
Version:          0.19.0
GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

lsb_release -a:

```
root@Debian-bullseye-latest-amd64-base \~ # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

I already reinstalled the howl server. Same output.